# Try to run several for loops in javascript to fill in info for a chart but getting errors

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Try to run several for loops in javascript to fill in info for a chart but getting errors
the user selects a certain amount of foods which then fills in arrays of food which has the name of the foods and then arrays of protein calories and fat that correspond to each food.

here is the code I have now. currently i get an error that says Uncaught `SyntaxError`: Unexpected token `var` :

```
var fat = $.parseJSON('<?php print(json_encode($fat, true)); ?>');
var calorie = $.parseJSON('<?php print(json_encode($calorie, true)); ?>');
var protein = $.parseJSON('<?php print(json_encode($protein, true)); ?>');
var food = $.parseJSON('<?php print(json_encode($food, true)); ?>');

series: [{
    for (var i=0;i<food.length;i++){
        name: food[i],
        data: for (var j=0;j<fat.length;j++){
                    calorie[j], protein[j], fat[j]
                }
        }
    }]
```

i copied the chart from a website they had the series like this

```
series: [{
                name: 'London',
                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]   
            }]
```

How would i fix my for loops to make it work.

```
script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var chart;
    var fat = $.parseJSON('<?php print(json_encode($fat, true)); ?>');


    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'MComparing foods is Awesome'
            },

            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return ''+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y +' mm';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series : []
    for (var i=0; i<food.length; i++) 
{
        series.push({
        name: food[i],
        data: [calorie[i], protein[i], fat[i]]});
}
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

and before

```
series:  [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]   
            }],
});
```

Comment: you want stacked bar? http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked

Comment: trying to do a basic column

Answer (score 4):

An object's property cannot be a `for` loop, as you're trying to do. It's simply not valid JavaScript syntax. (In Python, sure, a list comprehension would work – but this isn't Python.)

You need to create an array, *then* assign that as the property's value:

```
var series = [];

for (var i=0; i<food.length; i++) {

    series.push({
        name: food[i],
        data: [calorie[i], protein[i], fat[i]]
    });
}
```

The code in your question suggests a fundamental lack of understanding about JavaScript syntax; I recommend [reading about object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals).

Comment: my problem is that I am not sure how many properties I will need. could i put the food array that has all the food names as an array in the name property?

Comment: I suppose you could, but I really don't know what output data format you're going for because you haven't clearly shown it. For that matter, the question isn't clear about the _input_ data format.

Comment: is it possible to have a series with multiple names and data in which it depends on how many the user decides?

Comment: input is array of data in php in which i encode into json and set to a javascript variable. i have seperate arrays for food and catatories of data calories, protein, and fat

Comment: A series with multiple names? I don't know where this data is going so it depends. I'm not familiar with highcharts. Again, the **exact** input and output data formats matter, but you have not yet communicated them.

Comment: what would i input into name and what would go into data?

Comment: for each food that the user selects it compares the calories, protein and fat of each of the foods, so each name will have 3 inputs of data

Comment: input is in php which i encode to json and parse to javascript

Comment: output name is a string and data is an array of 3 numbers

Comment: Okay. How about adding small **example** of the input JSON, and the desired output data structure, to your question? Also, you don't need to keep posting 1-sentence comments – you can edit comments for up to 5 minutes after posting them.

Comment: input of food array in json: ["Brown Rice","Rainbow Jimmies","Feta Cheese","Suntan Pepper Strips","Steamed Whole Green Beans"]           example output name: 'Brown Rice',
        data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5]

Comment: say what do i put in name and what do i put in data? i understand that series contains objects.

Comment: My mistake - I'll edit the code and you can give that a shot.

Comment: having trouble with the syntax of it now. ill post more of my code in my question and what the format before i changed it so u get more of a full picture if thats alright.

Comment: error i am getting is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( after for statement

Comment: My code is clean, so you have probably not transcribed it correctly. http://jshint.com/

Comment: there shouldn't be a semicolon after series i dont think and series isnt declared as a var. it is series: [{entry 1}, {entry 2}...             ]

Comment: For that syntax to work, `series` needs to be part of some other object. The code will still have to look very similar to mine.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I haven't actually tried it but I am thinking something like:

```
series = new Array();
for (i=0;i<food.length;i++) {
    item = new Object();
    item.name = food[i];
    item.data = new Array();
    item.data = item.data.concat(calorie,protein,fat);
    series.concat(item);
}
```

Alright thanks to Matt's suggestions how about:

```
series = [];
for (i=0;i<food.length;i++) {
    item = {name: food[i], data: Array.concat(calorie,protein,fat)};
    series.push(item);
}
```

Comment: Why `new Array()` and `new Object()` instead of `[]` and `{}`, respectively? At that rate you could turn the first 3 lines of the loop body into `item = {name: food[i], data: []}`. Also, `Array.concat()` returns a new array, and does not mutate the original one.